# Varchar values to date format

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server 2014, I have a `varchar` column with multiple date formats:

```
shipdate
-----------
12/29/2014      -- mm/dd/yyyy
5/20/15         -- mm/dd/yy
2012/05/22      -- yyyy/mm/dd
```

I would like to convert them to `YYYY/MM/DD` date format but I can't, I tried with:

```
CAST(SRD.[ShipDate] AS DATEtime)
```

without success.

Any idea?

Comment: This is why you dont store dates in varchar columns. If you dont know the format of each row i think you're stuck with trying and failing and trying again for each row.

Comment: I wonder how you will decode 10/11/12  if no format info is available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmmmm . . . You really want to store dates as dates.  In your case, you can use `try_convert()` and keep testing until it works:

```
select coalesce(try_convert(date, shipdate),
                try_convert(date, shipdate, 1),
                try_convert(date, shipdate, 101)
               ) as presumed_date
```

Comment: Run this code, cross your fingers, and hope that none of your dates were ambiguous enough to be parsed incorrectly

Comment: it worked!, the weird thing here is that I have other column with the same values and format and with a simple cast worked :S

Answer (score 0):

CONVERT would work just fine, though the style would need to be 111.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CAST(SRD.[ShipDate] AS DATETIME),111);
```

Your code sample shows dates, though no time; additionally, I don't see that you want to see a time as per your question. Hence, I would suggest that you actually convert it to a DATE instead of DATETIME - as shown in the query below.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CAST(SRD.[ShipDate] AS DATE),111);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CAST(SRD.[ShipDate] AS DATE),111);
```

This should work because the style that your looking for is 111

Answer (score -1):

It is not clear whether you are trying to do this in a query or trying to migrate your data to a different column so my examples below need to be filled in and addapted to what your specific need is. (replace the ... as fit). You could apply a specific format and use try convert. Then iterate over your data set multiple times to catch all values.:

```
    SET DATEFORMAT mdy;  
    -- ... 
    TRY_CONVERT(datetime2, [ShipDate]) AS Result;
    -- ...  
    GO

    SET DATEFORMAT dmy;
    -- ... 
    TRY_CONVERT(datetime2, [ShipDate]) AS Result;
    -- ...
    GO

    -- ...
```